# Using UserNameResolver in Jenkins / Hudson

Tags: java, jenkins, spring-security, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

I'm trying to write a plugin that provides users' real name and email addresses from the data in our Active Directory. We use the ActiveDirectory plugin for authentication, which does not set these values (and, as far as I can tell, is unable to do so).

It works like a charm with the email address, but it seems the user's name is pre-filled with the user name used for authentication (the org.acegisecurity.userdetails.User), and the plugin is never queried to provide a real name.

How can I have Jenkins query my plugin for users' real names? I don't want to lose the actual user name by adding the real name lookup to the AD auth plugin so it returns the user's real name instead of the user name in UserDetails.

Comment: +1, looking forward to the plugin. I wish I could help with the question...

Comment: This has to be one of the oldest S/O [jenkins] tagged question with no answer! 9.5 years! Well done, Mr. Beck.